# Unique rails default form syntax to simple_form syntax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

Some time ago I had this form (in slim templating here) that I was unable to make work with simple_form, after 20 minutes I moved on, but I came back today and am curious about how this would translate in simple_form syntax. I use simple_form and I am familiar with the basic syntax, however I could not get this form to work properly.

```
= form_tag adminsessions_path do
    = text_field_tag :email, params[:email]
    = password_field_tag :password
    = submit_tag "LOG IN"
```

This the first I used this, idiom for lack of a better word (it is from the Railscasts diy authentication series recently). I'm just putting this out for interest in comments and gain a deeper understanding. What I have works for now.

Comment: Your question doesn't contain a single question mark. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: Perhaps, read my entry again.. Note 'am curious about how this would translate'. 'How would this translate into simple_form syntax?' is the implied question.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for specific questions. We shouldn't have to infer your question from a series of statements.

Comment: I appreciate your critique for forumulating future question, meagar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read through the simpleform documentation: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form

There you can find the correct syntax for several use cases, like this one:

```
    <%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
      <%= f.input :username %>
      <%= f.input :password %>
      <%= f.button :submit %>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: I know this already, if you would read the question you would note that I asked how that specific fragment would translate because the several variations I attempted did not work, but I did not go back over it recording copious notes.